# R ggplot2: Setting additional specific axis tick marks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot:

```
ggplot()+geom_line(data = data.frame(y = c(1,2,3), x=c(1,2,3)), aes(y=y,x=x))
```

[image]
I want to keep the default axis breaks and labels (In my program, I do not know the limits of the plot a priori.)

At x= 1.5 I want to add an additional tick mark to the x-axis with label "hi".

I know about `scale_x_continuous()`, but I do not know how to access the "default breaks computed by the transformation object".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ggplot2` uses the base function `pretty` (indirectly through `scales::pretty_breaks`) for non-transformed axes. Use this to your advantage:

```
df <- data.frame(y = c(1,2,3), x=c(1,2,3))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(pretty(df$x), 1.5), labels = c(pretty(df$x), 'hi'))
```

At 1.5 it will overplot of course (you write 'additional', not 'replace', so I'm not sure what you're after). If you don't want that, you'll need to do something like:

```
pretty_br <- pretty(df$x)[abs(pretty(df$x) - 1.5) > 0.25]
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(pretty_br, 1.5), labels = c(pretty_br, 'hi'))
```

[image]

Comment: By additional i meant "replace" if there already is a Label and add, if not. Therefore the second option will do. (could have made it clearer!)

Thank you!

Comment: How would you do this with a plot that has facets?