# R, ggplot2: add a specific tick + label to axis without changing other gridlines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a specific tick mark and label to an axis using `ggplot2`, without changing the rest of the axis or gridlines.

Let's say I have the following plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(x = c(0:100), y = c(0:100))

plot <- ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
plot
```

[image]

What I would like to do is add a specific tick mark and value on the y axis, to indicate a cut-off point of some sort. In the actual implementation, this cutoff and the data are to plot arguments passed to a function, so I want to do this without hard coding the values.

I found a solution to add a specific tick mark + label to an axis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51019320/r-ggplot2-setting-additional-specific-axis-tick-marks), which works correctly. Let's say in this case, I want to add it at y = 10. However, if I try it, the gridlines change as well:

```
plot + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(pretty(d$y), 10),
                          labels = c(pretty(d$y), 10))
```

[image]

Notice that now, rather than having major gridlines every 25 units and minor gridlines every 12.5 units, there are now major gridlines every 20 units and minor gridlines every 10. In addition, for some mysterious reason, an extra minor gridline has been added at y = 55.

Is there a way I can add the tick + label for y = 10, while otherwise making the y axis look like the first plot? Ideally, the solution would still allow me to use the `n.breaks` argument when setting up the y axis as well, so that I could request some number of breaks, and then add the extra one to that.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to have the reference line as part of the plot's grid, rather than a separate `geom_hline(yintercept = <whatever desired value>)` + annotated label?

Answer (score 1):

To use the method you wrote, you need to specify `minor.breaks` too.

```
plot + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(pretty(d$y), 10),
                          labels = c(pretty(d$y), 10), 
                          minor_breaks = pretty(d$y, n = 2*length(pretty(d$y))))
```

[image]

Comment: This fixes the issue with the extra minor gridline at y = 55, but it still changes the spacing of the minor gridlines to be every 10 units and the major gridlines to be every 20 units. I'd like to do this but keep the same minor/major gridlines as before (i.e., minor every 12.5 and major every 25). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Nevermind, I just figured it out! You do ```y_breaks <- c(ggplot_build(plot)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y$get_breaks(), 10);
y_labels <- y_breaks;
y_minor_breaks <- ggplot_build(plot)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y$get_breaks_minor();
plot + scale_y_continuous(breaks = y_breaks, labels = y_labels, minor_breaks = y_minor_breaks```

Answer (score 0):

Usually much easier and clearer to have a cut-off point as a hline as Z.Lin suggested. As even if it is on the axis it would probably still need a hline to get the desired effect.

E.g.

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(x = c(0:100), y = c(0:100))

plot <- ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
plot

plot +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 10, linetype = "dotdash", size = 0.9, alpha = 0.5)+
  annotate(geom = "text",x = 80, y = 14, label = "Cut-off point", fontface = 'italic')
```

Comment: Sorry---should have specified that I want to add an hline as well, though that wasn't difficult. The issue was that rather than annotating on the plot, I wanted to mark the value of the cut-off as an axis label, since I don't want to run the risk of the annotation overlapping with a data point. They don't in the toy example, but they might given an arbitrary data set.